# Finding all values satisfying constraints and visualizing the constraints in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following constraints

```
x1 = ("x1", "LowerBound",0);
x2 = ("x2","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
x3 = ("x3","LowerBound",0);
x4 = ("x4","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
x5 = ("x5","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);


x1 - (x4*x3) - x2 <=0;
x2 - ((2-x3)/3) <=0;
(x4*(x3))*(x2-((1-x3)/2))-(x1*(x2-x1+(x4*x3)))<=0;
```

Is there any way to visualize values satisfying these constraints and find all possible values satisfying these conditions in MATLAB?

Comment: Enumerating continuous solutions is difficult: there are likely infinitely many of them. Integer solutions are countable so that would make more sense.

Comment: Each inequation defines a region in the 4D space (have you noticed $x_5$ isn't present ?). A first question : is the intersection of the 3 regions nonvoid ? In a second step, consider one of the four variables for example $x_4$ as a parameter and make representations in the 3D space by letting $x_4$ vary.